# Angularjs Select not setted by $scope variable

Tags: angularjs, select

i have a very simple problem :

Here is my object  inside my controller :

```
$scope.footballeur = {'identifiant':6,'prenom':'Thierry','nom':'Chalamerto','categorie':1,'ville':'Paris','age':17,'date_embauche':'','salaire':'28'};
```

Please notice the int variable categorie .

Now in my view, i 've got a VERY SIMPLE select like this :

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon stdgp"></i> Catégorie</span>
    <select  ng-init="footballeur.categorie"  ng-model="footballeur.categorie" class="form-control" >
    <option  value="1">Junior</option>
    <option value="2">Confirmé</option>
</select>
</div><br>
```

Then, believe me or not, but the select is unable to get setted by my value.
It shows a blank line , it is really annoying.

I would really appreciate if somebody has an idea, the only thing who works is removing ng-model and replacing it by ng-value, but then, i can't save the new values chosen by the user !

I really dont know what to do, i 've tried ng-value instead of value, it still doesn't work !! I've removed ng-init, it changes nothing still ! there is not even a loop inside my SELECT , it is supposed to work directly !

here is a pic of the horrible situation :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER** (sorry I misunderstood your question at first glance)

I think your problem has to do with ["selected"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) attribute. Try something like this:

```
<option ng-selected="footballeur.categorie == 1" value="1">Junior</option>
```

**OLD ANSWER**

Make the select like this

```
<select ng-model="footballeur_selected" class="form-control">
  <option ng-repeat="(fname, fvalue) in footballeur" value="{{fvalue}}">{{fname}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Brilliant, your new answer works well, thank you a lot, i thought it was automatic, but obviously not !

Answer (score 1):

Look into using `ng-options` to set the `<select>` options.

Example (HTML):

```
<select class='form-control' 
    ng-model="mySelectedOption"
    ng-options="myOptions">
</select>
```

Example (JS):

```
$scope.myOptions = [
    { id: "option1", name: "Option 1" },
    { id: "option2", name: "Option 2" },
    { id: "option3", name: "Option 3" }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

**It works automatic !**
ng-init does not work that way. It is simple used to evaluate an expression.

**Your code works fine** even without ng-init.

```
<select  ng-model="footballeur.categorie" class="form-control" >
<option  value="1">Junior</option>
<option value="2">Confirmé</option>
</select>
```

Check out the [implementation](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWdLWJ)  here.